# SiFR Only replacing content 'above the fold'

Tags: sifr

I'm trying to use `siFR` to replace `H1` and `H2` content on my page but it appears to be only replacing the first two.

There are about 8 in all so some of them aren't on the page until you scroll down, and it appears that `siFR` is only replacing the items "above the fold"

I know next to nothing about javascript so can anyone tell me how to solve this so it replaces all of the `H1`'s and `H2`'s

Comment: You may provide some more information about your code to get an answer. There's probably just a silly detail you've missed out.

Comment: Which browsers is this happening in?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use servlets. This may help you solving your issue. You may find some good tutorials online.